# R- Autoplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, time-series, ggfortify

Hi I am running a ggfortify package in R, that allows customisation of time series plots in R.

See link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/basics.html.

The Link shows the example change of color on the plot:

```
library(ggfortify) 
autoplot(AirPassengers, ts.colour = 'blue')
```

In my code I have installed the packaged and loaded the library for ggfortify, however it doesn't display this ts.colour function as I type it.

My code:

```
autoplot(sales, ts.colour = 'blue')
```

resembles the above, but displays it in black, with the background the style should include but no difference to plot colour or thickness.

[image]

many thanks.

Comment: Has your `sales` data been converted to a time-series object using something like `as.ts(sales)`? If it's just a data-frame then `autoplot` won't work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The `ts.colour` argument will only work on a time-series object. If you run `str(sales)` it should return something like: "Time-Series [1:144] ..."

If it doesn't then you can try to convert it with: 

`ts(sales, start = c(2012, 1), end = c(2016, 2), 2)`

ggfortify tries to infer a lot of things from the plotted object, `sales`, so focus your attention there.  Good luck!

Comment: 'str(sales)
 Time-Series [1:18] from 2012 to 2016: 185 189 195 199 211 ...' is what appears as I have turned into a time series data set before, yet ts.colour and other functions do not seem to work. Thank you

Comment: That seems like a true bug, you might want to report it to the package authors ;)